# How to arrange image divs in rows of 3?

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

Hi all i got many divs that has class names such as **ItemLeft,ItemMiddle and ItemRight**. I wonder how i can display these image divs 3 in a row using css or any easy method(currently all the images display one below each other) ?

i get the image divs from getjson call as follows:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.awebsite.com/get?url=http://www.bwebsite.com/moreclips.php&callback=?', function(data){
    //$('#output').html(data.contents);

 var siteContents = data.contents;  

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=siteContents
```

**Note:** each time i call the getjson i get 6 image divs back that shows all below each other instead of 3 in a row!

and this the div images retrieved by making getjson call, but all these image divs below each other not 3 in rows:

```
<div class="ItemLeft">


  <div class="Clipping">        
    <a class="ImageLink" href="/videos/id1234" title="galaxy">
      <img class="ItemImage" src="/Images/galaxyimg.jpg" alt="galaxy" />
      <img class="OverlayIcon" src="/Images/1.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="DurationInfo" onmouseover="showDuration2(this);" onmouseout="hideDuration2(this);" href="/videos/id1234"><span class="Text">51:57</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="Title"><a href="/videos/id1234" title="galaxy">galaxy</a></div>

  <div class="VideoAge">1 daybefore</div>

  <div class="PlaysInfo"> broadcast 265</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question i have duplicated your leftItem to create multiple items and added a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/tVMet/

Provide float for your divs and end of the third just give a div clearing the float.

```
<div class="clear" />



.ItemLeft, .ItemMiddle, .ItemRight
{
    float:left;
}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: thanks. can you tell me how to create the css file and call it?i tried to test your demo locally but probably i didn't call the css style correctly and didn't work! how to give the divs float ? furthermore in my code i get <div class="LineSpacer3"></div> at the end of third div.

Comment: Can you put in a fiddle whatever you have and share it.

Comment: By the way you need to create a css file and just refer it in your page using <link href="pathtoyourcss" rel="Stylesheet" />. Is this what you mean by "how to create the css file and call it?"

Comment: i put the sample data in fiddle . hope you be able to help me fix it.http://jsfiddle.net/4nCu4/

Comment: Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/hknEp/ Your selector wasn't correct It should be '.Item.ItemLeft, .Item.ItemMiddle, .Item.ItemRight'. Please mark-vote for my answer if it works fine. Thanks

Comment: many thanks . the only problem i have that images are so big that forces each image item to next line when i check it with absolute image path and if i use non absolute image path that makes the divs 3 in line but without any image!!

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using tables in HTML. Or if you'd prefer div's without table cells, then try `float: left` for the three divs that need to be next to each other. And after every set, give a line break. This is to avoid all of them going on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I wonder if this can be done using css ? if yes can you guys show me how ?i will add a button (and name it showmore)that will call getjson to show more images and each time i press that button i will get 6 images added to list !

Comment: `float: left` IS CSS. The div that you put your image in will have a style of `float: left` with it. See answers below for details of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <div class="imagediv">

    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>
    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>
    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>

    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>
    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>
    <div class="imageitem"> // image content and stuff </div>

    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageitem {
   float:left;
}

.clearfloat {
   clear:both;
}
```